# Difference between DOM in Page Source and Inspect Element i

Tags: html, meta-tags, octobercms

I want to add a meta tag to one of my pages. However, I am using a CMS (ocotberCMS) which gives me access to only the body of the page. I attempted to add the meta tag to the markup looks like:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">
{% partial "temp-partial" %}
```

the result in page source and inspect element is different:

page source:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">
<div>
    .......// the body of the page generated by {% partial "temp-partial" %}
</div>
```

Inspect Element:

```
<html>
   #shadow-root
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    .......// the body of the page generated by {% partial "temp-partial" %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read that it is necessary to add the meta tag to the header according to the HTML4++ documentation. I was wondering if this means it will work in above case or it won't?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can only access the body of the page? If you have admin access to October then you should be able to access the layout too. If you don't have sufficient admin rights and the person who does is happy for you to insert meta tags then you could ask them add a placeholder (https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-placeholder) for you. If you say which of these cases applies, I can write a full answer for you.

Comment: @Joseph thanks, i don't know how i missed the `placeholder` tag. it's a very useful one in my case. i ned the tag only in a single page. (I wouldn't want to hide my entire site from search engines)

Comment: No problem. I've posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OctoberCMS has a "Placeholder" feature which is perfect for what you are trying to do:

https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-placeholder

You can use it in your HTML layout like this:

```
<html>
     <head>
         <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">
         {% placeholder meta %}
     </head>

     <body>
         {% page %}
     </body>
</html>
```

Then, later in any page:

```
{% put meta %}
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">
{% endput %}
```

Whatever is between the `{% put %}` tags will be put where the `{% placeholder %}` is in the layout when it is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the head section in the layout of the template.
Go to `CMS -> Layout -> default.htm` and add the meta tag there.

The actual layouts filename may differ but if you look at the html there, you should see which one is the main layout file.

Comment: correct. however, that would add the meta tag to my entire website. but i only need it for a single page. I read that search engines won't ignore the tag. so it should be fine

Comment: Then you can just add an if condition to check for that specific page. This is kind of a hack but its really straight-forward and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">` in the `<head>` section in your inspector DOM tree while it's in the `<body>` section of your source code and viewing the page source is because the inspector DOM tree is the version that has already been parsed by your browser.

Due to browsers being willing to accept what are known as "tag soup" (improper syntax and layout of HTML) and simply make their best guess on how it should work; the inspector DOM tree that your browser will show you is already the browser's best guess of what the code should be; regardless of the actual validity of that code.

So, in essence the reason why you see the meta tag in the body when you view the source is because that's where it actually is. The reason why you see it in the head section in your inspector is because the browser has guessed that the head section is the correct location for the meta tag.

To actually add it to your head section, where it is supposed to be for robots to actually see it, you will need to edit your CMS Layouts. If you do not have access to the CMS menu or the Layouts submenu, then your user account does not have permissions for that and you will have to get in contact with whoever built your site or ask for further help in IRC (freenode.net - #october) or Slack.

Answer (score 0):

Page source is what you see when creating a website.

Inspect element source includes generated data such as additional style attributes, database exports etc.

As for your question, try using Jquery and appending (http://api.jquery.com/append/) meta tag within the head.

Comment: so based on what you say inspect element shows me what browser will see. correct ? doesn't that make it ok to leave the tag like this. or that might not work ?

Comment: Exactly. Speaking of appending meta tag in body is invalid and it may cause bugs (source: Stack) so the browser might automaticly remove it

Comment: i got that. one more question. as you can see the meta tag is for search engines. how would search engines behave in this case ? similar to web browsers ? or will it see the meta tag any where in the page?

Comment: Search engines read only data within the head and few other tags located within your body (mostly h1 and h2 tags). So, it would probably ignore meta tag outside head tag.